# Технология использования связки Jsonmodel и Afnetworking

Tags: objective-c

Помогите решить возникшую проблему. Для подключения к JSON использую AFNetworking, а саму обработку полученных данных хочу организовать за счет JSONModel.

Вопрос в том, как перегнать данные в album_list. В старой версии JSONModel был метод arrayOfObjectsFromDictionaries. В новой его нет, и найти старую версию я не смог.

AlbumModel - модель данных.

```
   NSArray* album_list;
   ............

NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://ссылка на json"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

 AFHTTPRequestOperation *op = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
 op.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

 [op setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
     [self didReceiveJSON: responseObject];
     NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
 // Handle error
 }];

-(void)didReceiveJSON:(NSDictionary*)obj
{
    NSArray* results = obj[@"contents"];

       // ??? Вопрос здесь
       album_list = [AlbumModel arrayOfObjectsFromDictionaries:results];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оказалась кривая ссылка JSON. Поменял ссылку и отработал "arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries" [как говорил Bimawa](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/379543#379553).

Answer (score 1):

```
arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries
```

Чем не устраивает?

**Обновление**

```
NSArray* results = obj[@"contents"];
```

Тут вы получаете массив

```
[AlbumModel arrayOfObjectsFromDictionaries:results];
```

А тут вам надо уже словарь? Проверьте, что Вы скармливаете в `JSONModel`?

Comment: Не отрабатывает arrayOfModelsFromDictionaries.

Comment: Обновил ответ